# Forgot to Drop Temp Table, now I can't get Rid of It

Tags: temp-tables

I wrote a stored procedure and created a temp table #TempHitRatioTable.  I forgot to put the drop table statement in my procedure and now no matter what I do I can't get rid of the temporary table and can't re-execute the procedure.  I have tried completely disconnecting from the server and reconnecting, but it is still there.  I have tried the following statements:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHitRatioTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempHitRatioTable
```

and I also tried:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#TempHitRatioTable%')
DROP TABLE #TempHitRatioTable

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'#TempHitRatioTable') AND type = (N'U')) DROP TABLE #TempHitRatioTable
```

But I still can't get rid of that table.  My stored procedure is no longer running, nor is the crystal report I tried to run it on, but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: Can you connect to it through the Management studio?

Comment: Can I connect to what through SSMS?

Comment: 1) Where did you create your temp table, inside or outside of the stored procedure ? 2) When you try to delete it, do you get error messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.  I had put the create table at the bottom of the cursor inside of it, so each time the cursor iterated throught to add a new record the table was already created.  I moved the create table to the top of the stored procedure, before I created the cursor, added the statement: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHitRatioTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempHitRatioTable at the top of the procedure, then I added the drop table statement to the end of the procedure and all is well.  I can run it as many times as I want and get all my results back not just one record.  Silly me :-)